# how can i arrange a select box with the equal width of field,which is in data grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just wanna arrange it for all resolutions and for IE,firefox,crome of updated versions

[image]

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Can you show us some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: <div >
   <table style="width:100%;" >
<tr >
<td >
 <table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
   <td width="5%"><h1></h1></td>
   <td width="5%" align="right"><div  style="width:95%;"><span></span></div></td>
   <td  width="10%">
   <html:select  style="width:100%;" > 
      <html:option value=""></html:option>
      
   </html:select>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<table>
<div>

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your **css**, for example if you want the width to be 80%:

```css
    select {
      width: 80%;
      box-sizing: content-box;
      -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    }
```

```html
<select>
  <option>qwerty</option>
  <option>asdf</option>
</select>
```

*Can you add your code*

Comment: its not possible because its an ui  grid so can u help me in any other way ,,,,, the select box is in header part ..i have tried but i can fix it for only 1080p resolution . can u say me how can i arrange it for all resolutions